# How to get the exception information in 'catch(...)'

Tags: c++, exception

In C++, we can get the exception information through `catch(bad_cast& ex)`, then output the content of `ex.what()`

```
try{
     //…
}catch(std::bad_alloc& e)
{
    cout << “Catch bad alloc exception ” << e.what() << endl;
}
catch(std::bad_cast& e)
{
    cout << “Catch bad alloc exception ” << e.what() << endl;
}
catch(std::bad_exception& e)
{
    cout << “Catch bad alloc exception ” << e.what() << endl;
}
// catch more exception types here
// … 
catch(...)
{
    // how to get the content of unknown exception?
}
```

**How to get the exception information from `catch(...)`?**

Comment: In short: You can't reliably.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something the language by itself can do.

`...` literally means "anything".

Which operations can you safely do on the "anything" ?
You need in any case a type to check for. And that's noting more what you already did.